# SQL Distinct on one column only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the tables below

Table **GroupChat**

```
GroupChatId int
GroupCode varchar(20)
Name varchar(50)
```

Table **GCMembers**

```
ID int 
ParticipantUserID int
GroupChatID int
```

Table **Chats**

```
ID
Sender
Receiver
```

I run the following query

```
Select distinct GC.GroupChatID, GC.Name
from Chats chats 
inner join GroupChats GC on chats.Receiver = GC.GroupCode
inner join GCMembers GCM on GC.GroupChatID = GCM.GroupChatID 
where GCM.ParticipantUserID = 3
```

This works perfectly but I want to only have distinct `GroupChatID`. In other words if `GroupChatID` already exists in the result of the query don't bother adding it. Value `GCM.ParticipantUserID` comes from another table (foreign key) that doesn't have to do anything with this question so I didn't include that here. Any `int` value could work.

How can I achieve that? Thanks for your help in advance.

Sample Data

```
GroupChat
GroupChatID - GroupCode - Name
    1             GC1    Group1
    2             GC2     Group2
```

--

```
Chats
ID - SENDER - RECIEVER
 1      2        GC1
 2      3        GC2
 3      3        GC1
 4      3        GC1

GCMembers
ID - ParticipantUserID - GroupChatID
1           2                1
2          3                1
3           3                2
```

The output should be

```
GroupchatID:1 and Name:Group1
```

Comment: I would help if you showed exactly what output you expected with some sample data

Comment: I have added more information let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: With that data you won't get any results - Chats.Receiver is an integer but GroupChats.GroupCode is GC1, GC2 etc - these will never have matching values to JOIN on

Comment: the foreign key for that `GroupChatID`

Comment: Your query included ```from Chats chats inner join GroupChats GC on chats.Receiver = GC.GroupCode```    So, as I said the data types and values between ```chats.Receiver``` and ```GC.GroupCode``` do not match and no rows will return. Either your query or sample data is wrong

Comment: I was trying to simplify the data sample without all the other unnecessarily columns but it didnt workout. It should be good now

Comment: You filter ```GCMembers``` by ```ParticipantUserID = 3```.  Looking at the sample data that would still provide GroupChatID values of 1 AND 2.   Your data doesn't filter down to just 1 row. Do you just need the first row or do you expect to receive all the rows matching this filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228878/discussion-between-iamaaarianme-and-martin-cairney).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is `OVER(PARTITION BY...)`.

Unfortunately, I don't have an SQL server running at the moment, and I don't want to write code untested, but you can find examples here:
https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the rows, and select any value for `Name`. SQL does not have an `ANY` function, but you can use `MIN` or `MAX`:

```sql
Select GC.GroupChatID, MIN(GC.Name) AS Name
 from Chats chats inner join GroupChats GC on chats.Reciever=GC.GroupCode
inner join GCMembers GCM on GC.GroupChatID=GCM.GroupChatID 
where GCM.ParticipantUserID=3
GROUP BY GC.GroupChatID
```

Comment: this gives me an error saying that the other columns arent included in group by

Comment: You need to use an aggregation function on any column which you are not distincting on